Please explain anisotropic filtering
In games there is anisotropic filtering option that is supposed to make textures look sharper at a distance or at extreme angles. Is there a way to achieve this in blender somehow? Is it even needed in cycles?

@Lutzi The answer is 10 years old, Blender Internal was removed from 2.8 on... so you suggest he should go back to 2.79 for a solution?

@GordonBrinkmann Unlike what you suggested, I opened Blender 4.2.3 and found the same Filter: EWA settings under the Texture tab. No, I don't suggest 2.79, I suggest 4.2.3

@Lutzi Oh, I'm so stupid... I was looking in the Material tab ‍♂️ But does it have any effect on textures in the Shader Editor?

@GordonBrinkmann I think the equivalent filtering method in shader is the Interpolation setting in Image Texture. We need first to know what is the OP question here.
